# python - Pandas - FillNa with another non null row having similar column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I would like to fill missing value in one column with the value of another column.

I read that looping through each row would be very bad practice and that it would be better to do everything in one go but I could not find out how to do it with the fillna method.

Data Before

```
Day  Cat1  Cat2
1    cat   ant
2    dog   elephant
3    cat   giraf
4    NaN   ant
```

Data After

```
Day  Cat1  Cat2
1    cat   ant
2    dog   elephant
3    cat   giraf
4    cat   ant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and pass the df without `NaN` rows, setting the index to `Cat2` and then calling [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) which will perform a lookup:

```
In [108]:
df['Cat1'] = df['Cat1'].fillna(df['Cat2'].map(df.dropna().set_index('Cat2')['Cat1']))
df

Out[108]:
   Day Cat1      Cat2
0    1  cat       ant
1    2  dog  elephant
2    3  cat     giraf
3    4  cat       ant
```

So here I drop the `NaN` rows, and set the index to `Cat2`, by calling `map` on this it will lookup Cat1`values where`Cat2` matches

Here is the result of the `map`:

```
In [112]:
df['Cat2'].map(df.dropna().set_index('Cat2')['Cat1'])

Out[112]:
0    cat
1    dog
2    cat
3    cat
Name: Cat2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Wise solution. But doesn't work if `Cat2` is not unique. I would recommend doing `drop_duplicates("Cat2")` after `dropna()`